# TimeField - Not a valid choice

Tags: django

My model has a choices

```
MYCHOICES = (
    ('15:00:00', '3 PM'),
    ...
)
```

Field:

```
t = models.TimeField(choices=MYCHOICES)
```

form:
    Nothing extra for this field

When I select a choice, it says invalid choice.

I tried using datetime(python) values in choices but still that didnt work.

Any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried populating MYCHOICES with datetime.time instances?

Comment: As @samg86 said, you need to pass `datetime.time` instances, not just strings.
    from datetime import time
    MYCHOICES = (
        (time(15,0), '3 PM'),
        ...
    )

Answer (score 1):

REPEAT_CHOICES = (
    (time(15, 00, 00), u'3 PM'),
)

work for me